# How to make JavaScript canvases overlap other canvases

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById('PongPad1');
// var canvasSize = document.getElementById("PongPad1").style.height;
var PongPad1 = canvas.getContext('2d');

PongPad1.speed = 3;
PongPad1.w = 50;
PongPad1.h = 100;
PongPad1.x = "";
PongPad1.y = "";
if(PongPad1.x == ""){
PongPad1.x = 20;
}
if(PongPad1.y == ""){
PongPad1.y = 20;
}
function draw() {
 
PongPad1.fillStyle = 'black';
PongPad1.fillRect( PongPad1.x , PongPad1.y , PongPad1.w, PongPad1.h);

}
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 38) {
       PongPad1.clearRect(PongPad1.x, PongPad1.y, PongPad1.w, PongPad1.h)
       if(PongPad1.y > 0){
       PongPad1.y = PongPad1.y - PongPad1.speed;
       }
       draw();
//console.log(PongPad1.y);

    }
    });
    
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 40) {
      
   PongPad1.clearRect(PongPad1.x, PongPad1.y, PongPad1.w, PongPad1.h);
   //Canvas hieght - PongPad1.h
   if(PongPad1.y < 175){
       PongPad1.y = PongPad1.y + PongPad1.speed;
       }
     
       draw();
//console.log(PongPad1.y);

    }
    });
  
   var canvas1 = document.getElementById('PongPad2');
  
// canvas.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid; position: fixed; top: 8px; left: 8px; z-index: 0; width: 500px; height: 500px;');
 
                        
var PongPad2 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

PongPad2.speed = 3;
PongPad2.w = 50;
PongPad2.h = 100;
PongPad2.x = "";
PongPad2.y = "";
if(PongPad2.x == ""){
PongPad2.x = window.innerWidth - (40 + PongPad2.w);
}
if(PongPad2.y == ""){
PongPad2.y = 20;
}
function draw2() {
 
PongPad2.fillStyle = 'black';
PongPad2.fillRect( PongPad2.x , PongPad2.y , PongPad2.w, PongPad2.h);

}
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 87) {
       PongPad2.clearRect(PongPad2.x, PongPad2.y, PongPad2.w, PongPad2.h)
       if(PongPad2.y > 0){
       PongPad2.y = PongPad2.y - PongPad2.speed;
       }
       draw2();
PongPad2.fillRect( PongPad2.x , PongPad2.y , PongPad2.w, PongPad2.h);

    }
    });
    
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 83) {
      
   PongPad2.clearRect(PongPad2.x, PongPad2.y, PongPad2.w, PongPad2.h);
   //Canvas hieght - PongPad1.h
   if(PongPad2.y < 175){
       PongPad2.y = PongPad2.y + PongPad2.speed;
       }
     
       draw2();


    }
    });
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById('ball');
                 

var ball = canvas2.getContext('2d');

ball.speed = 1;
ball.w = 10;
ball.h = 10;
ball.dx = "";
ball.dy = "";
if(ball.dx == ""){
ball.dx = 1 * (Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1);

}
if(ball.dy == ""){
ball.dy = 1 * (Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1);
}

ball.x = "";
ball.y = "";
if(ball.x == ""){
ball.x = 960;
}
if(ball.y == ""){
ball.y = -300;
}
function draw3() {
 
ball.fillStyle = 'black';
ball.fillRect( ball.x , ball.y , ball.w, ball.h);

}

setInterval(() => {
ball.clearRect( ball.x , ball.y , ball.w, ball.h);



ball.x = ball.x + (ball.speed * ball.dx);
ball.y = ball.y + (ball.speed * ball.dy);
draw3();

if(ball.y < 0){
ball.dy = 1;
}
               //Math.round(window.innerHeight/2)
if(ball.y >  200){
ball.dy = -1;

}
draw3();
if(ball.x > window.innerWidth){
ball.dx = -1;
ball.speed = 1;
}
if(ball.x < 0){
ball.dx = 1;
ball.speed = 1;
}

if(PongPad1.x < ball.x + ball.w &&
    PongPad1.x + PongPad1.w > ball.x &&
    PongPad1.y < ball.y + ball.h &&
    PongPad1.y + PongPad1.h > ball.y)
{
ball.dx = 1;
//ball.speed++;
}
if(PongPad2.x < ball.x + ball.w &&
    PongPad2.x + PongPad2.w > ball.x &&
    PongPad2.y < ball.y + ball.h &&
    PongPad2.y + PongPad2.h > ball.y)
{
ball.dx = -1;
//ball.speed++;
}
//console.log(ball.y);
 }, 10);

    var test = window.innerWidth  ;
    var test2 = window.innerHeight ;
  document.getElementById("test").textContent = "" + test + "," + test2 + "";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="icon" href="Pangea 8 logo 3.png" type="image/x-icon">
   <meta name="keywords" content="Pangea 8"/>
   
    
  </head>
<style>
  .work{
  position: static;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  }
  
  
  
  </style>
  <body id="body">
    <p id ="test">
      hello
    </p>
   <div >
     <canvas class = "work" id="ball" height = "469px" width = "1900px"   ></canvas>
            <canvas class = "work" id="PongPad1" height = "275px"  >   </canvas> 
    <canvas class = "work" id="PongPad2" height = "275px" width = "1900px" ></canvas>
    </div>

             
    
     

             
</body></html>
```

^ Is my Pong game. Use W,S and Up, Down to make the paddles appear. I made the canvases have a green border so you can see them better. I want these canvases to be on the same plane, instead of the 3. They are not in synch, I need them to be. How can I make them overlap so they are on the same level?

Comment: `canvas` elements are just elements. You can arrange them the same way you arrange any other HTML element. Flex, grid, float, absolute/relative positioning...

Comment: Do you know which one of those would achieve the result I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
  position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```

this created my desired outcome.